# Clear jquery validation icons on form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, reset

I need to clear all the validation error messages and validation icons when clicking outside of the slide in menu.

But although the form reset and error messages are deleted, the cross mark remain unchanged. I need to remove all data when I click outside the menu.

[image]

I'm using below code to reset the form and remove validation messages.

```
<script>
  $('.overlay').on('click', function(){    
     $("#ohut-innate-form")[0].reset();    
     $('#navbarSide').removeClass('reveal');
     $('.overlay').hide();
     $(".error").html('');
     $(".error").removeClass("error");
     $("ohut-innate-form").validate().resetForm();   
  });
</script>
```

Here is my form

```
<form class="ohut-innate-form" id="ohut-innate-form" name="ohut-innate-form" method="post">
                        <span class="form-group">
                        <label >Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="emailReg" id="emailReg" class="validate" required>
                        </span>
                        <span class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="passwordReg" id="passwordReg" class="validate">
                        </span>
                        <span class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="validate">
                        </span>
                        <span class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" class="validate">
                        </span>
                        <span class="form-group">
                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" class="validate">
                        </span>
                        <input type="hidden" id="baseUrlReg" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn  btn-block btn-primary mr-2" name="Login">Register</button>
                       <!-- <a href="#"  name="Login"  id="register_user" onclick="registerUser()" class="btn  btn-block btn-primary mr-2">Register</a> -->

                        <div class="formrow left" style="visibility: hidden;">
                            <div class="mainlableContent">
                                <input class="formtext" type="text" name="mid" id="mid" value="<?php echo $merchantid; ?>" >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove right errorcross" id="email_cross" style=""></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

How can I remove the red cross?

Comment: Please click `<>` and post a [mcve]. It is now not possible to see how you set the errors and why changing class does not clear them

Comment: `$(window).click(function(){ $(".errorMessageClass").val(""); $(".crossClass").hide(); });`

Comment: @Martin now for the correct validations it shows a green ticks. I need all the ticks and crosses removed.

Comment: Simply target the elements you wish to do something with @ShavindiPathirana it's hard to help you 100% since you are using some customized classes (probably applying some css?) that we have no idea what actually does. Try to refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but since you tagged jQuery, you can use `$(window).click(function(){  });` to register clicks outside your elements and then apply a logic around that. You can target your elements by class, name or id, depending what seems like the most convenient.

Furthermore, When you exit an element, do you want to clear the validation messages and hide the cross of all elements, or just the one you exited?

Skimming your code, I think the best solution would be to go by the classes that you have on your different elements when it comes to clearing all of the messages etc.

An example would be:

```
$(window).click(function() {
    $(".error").html(''); //this is your validation/error message that will be cleared
    $('.right errorcross').hide(); //this is your red cross that will be hidden
});
```

Please note that this is half pseudo code, meaning that you'd have to tweak it to fit your logic, mainly since I don't know what your classes do specifically, since no code for them has been provided in your question.

Comment: you could add nested classes like you already have now, and call it "elementToClear" or something like that and target that. Then you would clear all elements that has that class. You could do the same with elements that you wish to hide, unless you already believe you have generic classes to go by, then obviously just use that.

Comment: Looking at the code you provided, it already seems like you have an understanding of how to clear and hide elements that you wish, and what you were really looking for was the function that would apply those changes upon exiting the element, which would be the function I provided. Simply use that to fit your logic. Like I also said previously, it's hard to give any further instructions without further information.